# i am getting 404 error while calling a url which is mapped to my api though my api is working

Tags: python, django, api

I am getting a 404 error when my API is mapped to the URL.
when I am running url I am getting a bad gateway, so I m bypassing 404 then the URL is giving results properly.

My API is running properly so I am not able to understand from where this 404 is coming.

can anyone help?

I tried debugging the program but I am not getting any code or line of code from where the error is originating.

my view.py is

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .apps import AutocatappConfig
from .apps import TaggenerationConfig
from AutoCatApp.inference import inference
from AutoCatApp.portal_search import *
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes
from AutoCatApp.auth import CustomAuthentication
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
import time
import gc

# Create your views here.



@api_view(['POST','GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def feedback_type(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return JsonResponse(
            {"WARNING": "GET method is not allowed for this API"}, safe=False)
    else:
        run = inference()
        ps=time.time()
        gc.collect()
        print("process start:-",ps)
        if len(request.data) > 0:
            req_body = dict(request.data)
            q1 = ""
            q2 = ""
            if (req_body.get('title') is not None):
                q1 = request.data['title']
            if (req_body.get('description') is not None):
                q2 = request.data['description']
            if q1!="" or q2 != "":
                #i=input_data()
                q3 = q1+" "+q2
                result = run.predict(q3)
                pe = time.time()
                print("end time:-",pe)
                print("total time taken is :-",pe-ps)
                return JsonResponse({"Feedback Type": result}, safe=False)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"WARNING": "Please provide either title and description to provide feedback"},safe=False)

        else:
            return JsonResponse({"WARNING": "The Input is Null, Please provide some input!"},safe=False)

@api_view(['POST','GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def generating_tag(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return JsonResponse(
            {"WARNING": "GET method is not allowed for this API"},safe=False)
    else:
        ps=time.time()
        print("process start:-",ps)
        if len(request.data) > 0:
            req_body = dict(request.data)
            q1 = ""
            q2 = ""
            if (req_body.get('title') is not None):
                q1 = request.data['title']
            if (req_body.get('description') is not None):
                q2 = request.data['description']
            if q1!="" and q2 != "":
                #i=input_data()
                result_2d=TaggenerationConfig.rnn.caller(q1, q2)
                pe = time.time()
                print("end time:-",pe)
                print("total time taken is :-",pe-ps)
                return JsonResponse({"Tag generated": result_2d}, safe=False)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"WARNING": "Please provide both title and description to generate hashtags"},safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"WARNING": "The Input is Null, Please provide some input in title and description to generate hashtags"},safe=False)

@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@authentication_classes((CustomAuthentication,))
def search_funcationality(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return JsonResponse({"WARNING": "GET method is not allowed for this API"},safe=False)
    else:

        gc.collect()
        s0 = time.time()
        q1 = request.data.get('query_text', "")
        q2 = request.data.get('asset_type', "")
        q3 = request.data.get('Accelerator_filter', "")
        q4 = request.data.get('DocumentAssetType', "")
        q5 = request.data.get('Industry_filter', "")
        q6 = request.data.get('Function', "")
        q7 = request.data.get('Technology', "")
        q8 = request.data.get('Format', "")
        q9 = request.data.get('Geography', "")
        page = request.data.get('page', 0)
        num_of_obj = request.data.get('object_return', 6)
        sort_by = request.data.get('sort_by', "")
        sort_order = request.data.get('sort_order', "")
        hasquote = request.data.get('hasquotes', 'False')
        # hasquote="False"
        if hasquote == 'False':
            query = " ".join([w.lower() for w in q1.split() if not w.lower() in stop_words])
        else:
            query, n = re.subn('[_|-]', ' ', q1)
        print("query in views .py", query)
        if q1 != "":
            if len(query) > 0:
                if q2 != "" and q3 == "" and q4 == "" and q5 == "" and q6 == "" and q7 == "" and q8 == "" and q9 == "":
                    if q2 == 'Documents':
                        documents_result, len_of_documents_result, Doc_Type_List, Industry_List, Function_List, Technology_List, Format_List, geography_List, AssetType_counts = search_main(
                            query, hasquote, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, sort_by, sort_order)
                        paginator = Paginator(documents_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                        try:
                            documents_result = paginator.page(page)
                        except EmptyPage:
                            documents_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

                        return JsonResponse(
                            {"TotalCount": len_of_documents_result, "DocumentAssetType": documents_result.object_list,
                             "DocumentType": Doc_Type_List, "Industry": Industry_List, "Function": Function_List,
                             "Technology": Technology_List, "Format": Format_List, "Geography": geography_List,
                             "AssetType_counts": AssetType_counts}, safe=False)
                    elif q2 == 'Golden Templates':
                        golden_template_result, total_number_of_result = search_main(query, hasquote, q2)

                        paginator = Paginator(golden_template_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                        try:
                            golden_template_result = paginator.page(page)
                        except EmptyPage:
                            golden_template_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                        return JsonResponse(
                            {"TotalCount": total_number_of_result, "GTAssetType": golden_template_result.object_list},
                            safe=False)
                    elif q2 == 'Client Story':
                        client_story_result, total_number_of_result = search_main(query, hasquote, q2)
                        paginator = Paginator(client_story_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                        try:
                            client_story_result = paginator.page(page)
                        except EmptyPage:
                            client_story_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                        return JsonResponse(
                            {"TotalCount": total_number_of_result, "ClientStoryAssetType": client_story_result.object_list},
                            safe=False)
                    else:
                        accelerator_result, total_number_of_result, Level1_list, Industry_List, Function_List, Technology_List = search_main(
                            query, hasquote, q2)
                        paginator = Paginator(accelerator_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                        try:
                            accelerator_result = paginator.page(page)
                        except EmptyPage:
                            accelerator_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                        return JsonResponse(
                            {"TotalCount": total_number_of_result, "AccelaratorAssetType": accelerator_result.object_list,
                             "AcceleratorPhase": Level1_list, "Industry": Industry_List, "Function": Function_List,
                             "Technology": Technology_List}, safe=False)
                elif q2 == "Accelerator" and (q3 != "" or q5 != "" or q6 != "" or q7 != "" or q8 != "" or q9 != ""):
                    accelerator_result, total_number_of_result, Level1_list, Industry_List, Function_List, Technology_List = search_main(
                        query, hasquote, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9)
                    paginator = Paginator(accelerator_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                    try:
                        accelerator_result = paginator.page(page)
                    except EmptyPage:
                        accelerator_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                    return JsonResponse(
                        {"TotalCount": total_number_of_result, "AccelaratorAssetType": accelerator_result.object_list,
                         "AcceleratorPhase": Level1_list, "Industry": Industry_List, "Function": Function_List,
                         "Technology": Technology_List}, safe=False)
                elif q2 == "" and q3 == "" and q4 == "" and q5 == "" and q6 == "" and q7 == "" and q8 == "" and q9 == "":
                    total_number_of_result, accelerator_result, golden_template_result, documents_result, client_story_result = search_main(
                        query, hasquote)
                    return JsonResponse({"TotalCount": total_number_of_result, "GTAssetType": golden_template_result,
                                         "AccelaratorAssetType": accelerator_result, "DocumentAssetType": documents_result,
                                         "ClientStoryAssetType": client_story_result}, safe=False)
                else:
                    documents_result, len_of_documents_result, Doc_Type_List, Industry_List, Function_List, Technology_List, Format_List, geography_List, AssetType_counts = search_main(
                        query, hasquote, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, sort_by, sort_order)
                    paginator = Paginator(documents_result, num_of_obj)  # to show 10 products
                    try:
                        documents_result = paginator.page(page)
                    except PageNotAnInteger:
                        documents_result = paginator.page(1)

                    except EmptyPage:
                        documents_result = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
                    return JsonResponse(
                        {"TotalCount": len_of_documents_result, "DocumentAssetType": documents_result.object_list,
                         "DocumentType": Doc_Type_List, "Industry": Industry_List, "Function": Function_List,
                         "Technology": Technology_List, "Format": Format_List, "Geography": geography_List,
                         "AssetType_counts": AssetType_counts}, safe=False)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"error_message": "Please enter the long text you wanted to search!"}, safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"error_message": "Please enter the text you wanted to search!"}, safe=False)




@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def healthz(request):
     return JsonResponse({"result": "OK - healthy"},status=200)
```

and my urls.py is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from AutoCatApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('autocat', views.feedback_type),
    path('hashtaggenerator', views.generating_tag),
    path('smartsearch', views.search_funcationality),
    path('autocat/healthz', views.healthz)
]
```